# How do I select specific values in a row to average if another number in the row equals a certain value?

Tags: r, matrix, average

I apologize for the title of this question but it's difficult to explain in one line unless you see the question.

So lets say I have a table of log Fold change values (logFC columns) and FDR (false discover-rate) values associated with them (BH columns).

```
data <- matrix(NA,10,6)
colnames(data) <-c("logFCa","BHa","logFCb","BHb","logFCc","BHc")
data
row.names(data) <- LETTERS[seq(from = 1,to = 10)]

data[,1] <- 1
data[,2] <- c(1.000 ,0.001, 0.500, 0.500, 0.500, 0.010, 0.001, 0.200, 0.001, 0.001 )
data[,3] <- 2
data[,4] <- c(0.500 ,0.200 ,0.300, 0.001 ,0.020, 1.000, 0.001, 0.001, 3.000 ,0.001 )
data[,5] <- 3
data[,6] <- c(0.4000, 0.6000 ,0.5000, 0.4000, 0.7000, 0.0001, 0.9900, 0.0010, 0.0010, 0.0010 )

logFCa   BHa logFCb   BHb logFCc    BHc
A      1 1.000      2 0.500      3 0.4000
B      1 0.001      2 0.200      3 0.6000
C      1 0.500      2 0.300      3 0.5000
D      1 0.500      2 0.001      3 0.4000
E      1 0.500      2 0.020      3 0.7000
F      1 0.010      2 1.000      3 0.0001
G      1 0.001      2 0.001      3 0.9900
H      1 0.200      2 0.001      3 0.0010
I      1 0.001      2 3.000      3 0.0010
J      1 0.001      2 0.001      3 0.0010
```

What I would like to do is calculate the mean of logFCa, logFCb, and/or logFCc if two or more of the associated BH values are less than 0.01. My first attempt was as follows. If BHa was < 0.01 I made a column to identify it with the number 1, if BHb was < 0.01 I made a column to identify it with the number 3, and if BHc was < 0.01 I made a column to identify it with the number 5. Then I made a column to sum those numbers for each row.

```
#BHa < 0.01 = 1
#sigA
sigA <- ifelse(data[,2]<0.01, 1 , NA )
data <- data.frame(data, sigA)

#BHb < 0.01 = 3
#sigB
sigB <- ifelse(data[,4]<0.01, 3, NA )
data <- data.frame(data, sigB)

#BHc < 0.01 = 5
#sigC
sigC <- ifelse(data[,6] < 0.01 , 5, NA )
data <- data.frame(data, sigC)

#Make column of row sums
keep <- c("sigA", "sigB", "sigC")
dataABC <- data[keep]
dataABC
data$ABC <- rowSums(dataABC, na.rm =TRUE)
```

So now I have this…

```
> data
  logFCa   BHa logFCb   BHb logFCc    BHc sigA sigB sigC ABC
A      1 1.000      2 0.500      3 0.4000   NA   NA   NA   0
B      1 0.001      2 0.200      3 0.6000    1   NA   NA   1
C      1 0.500      2 0.300      3 0.5000   NA   NA   NA   0
D      1 0.500      2 0.001      3 0.4000   NA    3   NA   3
E      1 0.500      2 0.020      3 0.7000   NA   NA   NA   0
F      1 0.010      2 1.000      3 0.0001   NA   NA    5   5
G      1 0.001      2 0.001      3 0.9900    1    3   NA   4
H      1 0.200      2 0.001      3 0.0010   NA    3    5   8
I      1 0.001      2 3.000      3 0.0010    1   NA    5   6
J      1 0.001      2 0.001      3 0.0010    1    3    5   9
```

But I want to have the following column with the mean of the logFC values if the associated BH columns are less than 0.01. What I want to do is say...

if column ABC is less than 4, make it "NA"

4 = average of logFCa and logFCb

5 = "NA"

6 = average of logFCa and logFCc

8 = average of logFCb and logFCc

9 = average of logFCa and logFCb and logFCc

so the final table would look like…

```
 logFCa   BHa logFCb   BHb logFCc    BHc sigA sigB sigC ABC means
A      1 1.000      2 0.500      3 0.4000   NA   NA   NA   0    NA
B      1 0.001      2 0.200      3 0.6000    1   NA   NA   1    NA
C      1 0.500      2 0.300      3 0.5000   NA   NA   NA   0    NA
D      1 0.500      2 0.001      3 0.4000   NA    3   NA   3    NA
E      1 0.500      2 0.020      3 0.7000   NA   NA   NA   0    NA
F      1 0.010      2 1.000      3 0.0001   NA   NA    5   5    NA
G      1 0.001      2 0.001      3 0.9900    1    3   NA   4   1.5
H      1 0.200      2 0.001      3 0.0010   NA    3    5   8   2.5
I      1 0.001      2 3.000      3 0.0010    1   NA    5   6   2.0
J      1 0.001      2 0.001      3 0.0010    1    3    5   9   2.0
```

Don't be mistaken, that last mean of 2.0 was calculated from all three logFC values (i.e. 1,2 and 3) to calculate an average of 2 as opposed to the value 2.0 in the row above it which was calculated from logFCa and logFCc. Any help would be greatly appreciated!!! Thanks!

edit. I should add that this example is just a test dataset. I would like to apply this technique to a matrix with approximately 6000 rows, but a similar number of columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you just want the `means` column. This should do it:

```
df         <- data.frame(data)
df$include <- with(df,(BHa<0.01)+(BHb<0.01)+(BHc<0.01)>1)
df$means   <- apply(df,1,function(x) 
                           ifelse(x[7],mean(x[2*which(x[c(2,4,6)]<0.01)-1]),NA))
df         <- df[,-7]   # get rid of column "include"
df
#   logFCa   BHa logFCb   BHb logFCc    BHc means
# A      1 1.000      2 0.500      3 0.4000    NA
# B      1 0.001      2 0.200      3 0.6000    NA
# C      1 0.500      2 0.300      3 0.5000    NA
# D      1 0.500      2 0.001      3 0.4000    NA
# E      1 0.500      2 0.020      3 0.7000    NA
# F      1 0.010      2 1.000      3 0.0001    NA
# G      1 0.001      2 0.001      3 0.9900   1.5
# H      1 0.200      2 0.001      3 0.0010   2.5
# I      1 0.001      2 3.000      3 0.0010   2.0
# J      1 0.001      2 0.001      3 0.0010   2.0
```

First, we append a column `include` which = T if two or more of the `BH` are <0.01.
Then, we "apply" a function to each row of `df` in succession. The function does this: if `include=F` for that row, return NA, otherwise identify which of the `BH` columns are < 0.1 and calculate the mean of the corresponding `logFC` columns.